# activate onClick of an element only if not clicked on certain child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

```
<div onClick={()=>do_stuff()}>
  <div classname="div-1"></div>
  <div classname="div-2"></div>
  <div classname="div-3"></div>
  <div classname="div-4"></div>
  <div classname="div-5"></div>
</div>
```

When the parent is clicked, it should only call the callback if for example, the click did not include `div-4`, `div-5` etc.

How to implement this in React?

Comment: You can add one more class in your div then when you click the parent just check the div is containing the classname or not if contains then add active class if not then do not add the class, you can use if else or for loop for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.stopPropogation()` solves this very easily.

```
<div onClick={()=>do_stuff()}>
  <div classname="div-1"></div>
  <div classname="div-2"></div>
  <div classname="div-3"></div>
  <div classname="div-4" onClick={(event) => event.stopPropogation()}></div>
  <div classname="div-5" onClick={(event) => event.stopPropogation()}></div>
</div>
```

With nested HTML elements, click events work their way up the heirarchy. Child components have their onclicks fire first. Parent components onclicks fire after. Doesn't matter how deeply nested the elements are, click events will always fire at the lowest nested level first, eventually 'propogating' all the way back up. You can stop the clicks from 'propogating' any further up by calling `stopPropogation()`. Once the callback with the stop propogation is executed, the rest of the call stack is simply erased.

Answer (score 1):

You could check `event.target` with `Element#matches`.

```js
function do_stuff(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.div-4, .div-5')) {
    console.log('click');
  }
}
```

```
<div onClick={do_stuff}>
    { /* ... */ }
</div>
```